# PHP Stopping E-mail Injections

Tags: php, email, code-injection

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
function spamcheck($field)
  {
  //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //filter_var() validates the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
  {//if "email" is filled out, proceed

  //check if the email address is invalid
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_REQUEST['email']);
  if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
    {
    echo "Invalid input";
    }
  else
    {//send email
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    mail("someone@example.com", "Subject: $subject",
    $message, "From: $email" );
    echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
    }
  }
else
  {//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br />
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>";
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

please explain me this program...

Comment: It takes a message, subject and sender email address, validates the address and if valid, sends a mail to `someone@example.com`.

Comment: What is your question and what don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Explain? Well, basically if someone hasn't filled the mail form, the form is shown. Otherwise, the function spamcheck controls if the mail address is valid. If it is, then it fills up the informations for the mail() function and sends the e-mail. If it's not, then shows the input is invalid.

I don't think it's the safest script around though...

Answer (score -1):

This is how to stop E-mail Injection

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
{//if "email" is filled out, proceed
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    mail("someone@example.com", "Feedback",
    "From: $email\n\nSubject: $subject\n\n$message");
    echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
}
else
{//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br />
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain *why*.

Comment: @Felix I doubt it would worth the efforts. I doubt the OP would pay any attention to his question, if he didn't already.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: It is not only about the OP it is also about others who see this and/or have a similar question. But it's your decision.

Comment: @Felix LOL, don't make laugh even more: ) hardly a few people would ever notice this question ever. there are already billions of the same crap. One of ten thousand, one with enormous rating - may be. But definitely not this one. It definitely doesn't worth. this is charity site, dude, not knowledge base. Immediate working code - that's what everyone asks from it, nothing more. One who able to find, will find all explanations already - there are a plenty. One who is unable to find - will never see my answer.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Why do you post at all if you obviously don't care?

Comment: @Felix I do care, and I almost don't post.